# Save contact to mobilbe phone Using flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, contacts

Ive been reading a lot of discussion regarding saving a contact to mobile from web.The only available is for IOS/Android. im currently working on a Flutter web project were i have "save to contact" button.Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you know how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm saving the contact information as Vcard in flutter web with the following code without any extra plugins. This will save the contacts to all devices.

Note: I used Vcard version 1.0, but that was complex and it didn't saved to contacts on Android. Only V3 is working without errors.

***Tested on android, iOS (Safari only), macOS, windows***

```
import 'dart:html' as html;


Future<void> addToContactsFn() async {
    final String vCard3Text = '''
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:${d.name}
UID:${d.id}
EMAIL:${d.email ?? '-'}
TEL;TYPE=WORK:${d.phoneNumber}
URL:${d.website ?? '-'}
NOTE:Created on ${AppInfo.appName}
N:${d.name};;;;;
END:VCARD''';
    final html.Blob blob = html.Blob(<String>[vCard3Text]);
    final String url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    final html.AnchorElement _ = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
      ..target = 'blank'
      ..download = '${d.name}.vcf'
      ..click();
    html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
  }
```

Comment: it works and use a world-wide stadard like VCF, thats mean that you can use this solution EVERYWHERE and for everyone.
Thanks a lot @Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Closest to save a contact in the browser is to [share](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) [vcard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard).